# Mail Connection issues to aol with yosemite 10.10.1

Tags: macbook-pro, email, macos

After I upgraded my macbook pro to yosemite 10.10.1, suddenly the mail won't connect to the aol mail.  It returns with error message "Mail cannot connect to aol account" and continuously asks for the password.  The password and account info is correct as I can log in using the same credentials on the web and the same mail was working just before the upgrade.  Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone.  I have the same problem using earthlink as email provider.  Answer is that you use "MacMail" on your computer which connects to your provider.  The connection is broken in the yosemite system.  Earthlink support has tried to remotely check and reset internal macmail settings in my computer, with no success.  Call your provider, maybe the can reset some hidden setting in yosemite.  Good luck.